# Geometric proof

Tags: geometry

Let the three sides of a triangle be $a,b$ and $c$. If the equation

> $$a^2+b^2+c^2=ab +bc+ac$$

holds true, then the triangle is an equilateral triangle.

How do we prove this? An answer or even the slightest hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = ab + bc + ca \implies (a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 = 0$$
I trust you can finish it off from here.

Comment: Thank you.I of course would love to know how you figured it out that quick.

Comment: @rahul Experience.

Comment: @rahul, times 2 on both sides.

Comment: @Easy,I understood that.What I meant was how it took him hardly a minute to have proved it,which, as he says,is experience.

Comment: @Easy you are right from experience and memory this type of thing we can solve easily.